# How to get the reference of the menu item in onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-menu, wifimanager

I have a menu item on the `action bar` (Wifi icon).I am able to change the icon with changing the state of the wifi( `WIFI_ON` and `WIFI_OFF`), and I can check the state of the wifi on starting of my app in `onCreate()` method using `wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()`, but the problem is that I could not set the icon of the menu item in `onCreate` method.because initially, it will always show the WIFI_OFF icon (no matter wifi is `ON` or `OFF`)until the menu item is clicked.

Here is the on onOptionItemSelected() method

```
case R.id.wifi_status:
            if (!isWifiEnabled) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.wifi_on);
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                isWifiEnabled = true;
            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.wifi_off);
                isWifiEnabled = false;
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
```

This is the Screenshot of the app when activity is start, as this can be seen the wifi button on action bar is off no matter the wifi is `ON` or `OFF`
[image: Screenshot of the app when activity starts]

Comment: You'd do that in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, not in `onCreate`.

Comment: I have used that, but the thing is that initially when the app runs it will always show the WIFI_OFF icon, no matter what is current status of the wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd typically set initial value when menu is inflated in `onCreateOptionsMenu` (assuming below your menu is `R.manu.main_menu`)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem wifiMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.wifi_status);

    // set wifiMenuItem state here based on wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Jhon O'Reilly, can I ask one more question, that how to fill some data on a webpage.

Comment: Oh sorry, don't you understand what am I saying, I mean something like filling the username and password on any website(Like facebook)